# Call to a member function get_results() on null

Tags: php, database, wordpress

I'm building a Wordpress site and for some application, an external website needs to access one of my page `destination.php` by the URL adress. So, I place this page at the root of my website. This page `destination.php` needs to access a table from my database. I thought using `$wpdb` would be enough to access any table but this variable does not seem to be initialized as a get the following error
     Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_results() on null

Following various advice from this forum, I tried :

1. `require_once('../wp-config.php');`

Then I get this error

```
 Warning : require_once([...]/wp-settings.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in [...]
```

As advised for security reasons, `wp-config` is not in the root folder and so `wp-config` and `wp-settings` are not at the same level. Thus `wp-config` does not seem to be able to find `wp-settings`. I don't know if (and how) I should modify `wp-config` to provide it with the right path

2. `require_once('wp-load.php');`

Then I have no error and my script stops running. Thus I don't know what it's going wrong with `wp-load`. It is in the same folder as my file `destination.php`.

A minimal example is as follows

```
<?php

//require_once('../wp-config.php');
require_once('wp-load.php');

echo 'loading complete';

global $wpdb; 

$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM my_table" );

?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I've been stuck there for many days...

Comment: as an alternative, just use `destination.php` as a template then create an empty page and link said template to page, then you can go on with wordpress api and functions and whatnot just like any normal page

Comment: My page `destination.php` must not display anything (the `echo` is just for debugging purpose) so I don't think a normal page can do the job as it will at least display a title

Comment: what i mean above is so that you can control it from the actual template, you're just putting it inside a template so that you'd still get the whole wordpress functionality and whatnot, you don't need to output anything if its required

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean but my page `destination.php` must not redirect to another page, it has to access the database by itself.

Comment: im not sure you understand me too, it seems we are at an impasse, i never said anything about redirection, im just saying that page will just be blank, or anything you could want, my suggestion is just put an empty template so that you'll have everything with wpdb at your disposal. right now ur just requiring one file from wordpress and it has so many dependencies, its much better if your file is inside the actual structure so that you can use the full api